# Magento - Where's Browse Image Button to Inserting Images?

Tags: image, magento, backend

I have a serious problem. None of my registered products have the button insert images. I am not sure what I did to make it happen, because a product registered at the beginning is normal and aparence photos. But it is impossible to change them or delete them. I do not understand what the problem is. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: Do you have flash player installed on your system?

Comment: Yes I have, it's a problem?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/magento-1-9-no-upload-image-buttons

Comment: @Bruno Is this fixed for you?

Comment: FIxed! Tks friend! :)